# Ubuntu 13.10 and AMD Radeon 8240

Tags: ati, radeon

I just bought a brand new Pacakard Bell PC and tried to install Ubuntu (EFI) on it. When installation finished and PC restarted, Ubuntu cannot launch lightdm. Instead I have a prompt asking me if I wish to start in low graphic mode. But no effect if I click yes. Screen stay black a while and I come back to terminal.

I understood there are troubles with the free Radeon driver. Is there any issues?